# Upload PDF files into newsstand using Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Desc: The objective of my project is to create a Newsstand Application on iOS.

For instance,  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/helloks.jpg/ is what I have done. This application allows reading of PDF files. However, I'm still unable to find any resources/codes on the web that teaches me how to insert a PDF file into Newsstand for users to view and download.

I have followed the tutorial from http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/ 
However I'm stucked at the step "Displaying and Downloading Magazines".
Please Assist!

Answer (score 2):

You can find source code of that tutorial [here](https://github.com/viggiosoft/NewsstandTutorial).

First pay attention to tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath [method](https://github.com/viggiosoft/NewsstandTutorial/blob/master/Newsstand/StoreViewController.m#L147). It gets cell information from ***publisher*** object. Let's look through **Publisher** class.

Publisher has [getIssuesList](https://github.com/viggiosoft/NewsstandTutorial/blob/master/Newsstand/Publisher.m#L39) method, which retrieves list of issues.

```
NSArray *tmpIssues = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.viggiosoft.com/media/data/blog/newsstand/issues.plist"]];
```

Now let's see what happens when user selects cell. [Here](https://github.com/viggiosoft/NewsstandTutorial/blob/master/Newsstand/StoreViewController.m#L184) we can find the following lines

```
...

if (nkIssue.status==NKIssueContentStatusAvailable) {
    [self readIssue:nkIssue];
} else if(nkIssue.status==NKIssueContentStatusNone) {
    [self downloadIssueAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Method called [downloadIssueAtIndex:](https://github.com/viggiosoft/NewsstandTutorial/blob/master/Newsstand/StoreViewController.m#L207) is responsible for downloading issue.

You have to be familiar with asynchronous requests of NSURLConnection to understand how it works.